# JsonPathResultMatchers cannot be applied to ResultMatcher

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to make a simple test using spring boot.

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/user")
       .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userJohn)))
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].username", is("bob")));
```

Using this import for the jsonPath:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
```

I get:

```
andExpect (org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher) in ResultActions cannot be applied to (org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath)
```

If i try to cast it to (ResultMatcher) i get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers cannot be cast to org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher
```

I'm using the version 2.0.4 of Spring boot.
Any ideas of what can be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try it:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/user")
   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userJohn)))
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].username").value("bob"));
```

I don't know when these changes. see more :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/JsonPathResultMatchers.html